# Uknown source of sublinks

Tags: seo, google-search-console, redirects, google-search, wordpress

I have recently took over the admin rights to my webpage from a company I had outsourced to create it, they however left the job undone and now my SEO sublinks are appearing in Portuguese.

I have researched how to block them being read by robots.txt however the links are all directing to my main page so when I block any link URL on robots.txt it also blocks my homepage from being read.

eg. `example.com/#A%20Empresa` will redirect to `example.com/#A Empresa`

Can anyone give me a hint as to what to do to remove these links or why it is happening?

Comment: what links? and you're blocking things from being read from robots.txt? I'm a bit confused.  To me, robots.txt file should be an accessible file, especially for search engines.

Comment: @Mike That question made sense before the edit... Simon made the right edit to save the question from being closed (of course)! Not a comment there. I am glad he saved this question. If you click the edited *n* hours ago link will show you the question as originally written. I was not sure if you knew that. Please do not be insulted if you did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason `example.org/#anything` redirects to `example.org` is quite easy. The browser always requests only the part before the `#`. The rest of the URL is the hash that points to any named link on the website. So your browser tries to find a link named `A Empresa` to scroll to after loading the page.

You cannot exclude those links in the `robots.txt` as long as you want the main page to be indexed, as you already found out.

In [this article](http://www.entrepreneur.com/article/220195) you should find out how to edit those sub links:

> To demote a sitelink URL, follow these five steps:
>
> - Login to your [Google Webmaster Tools](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/home) account
> - On the Webmaster Tools Home page, click the site you want to edit.
> - Under Site configuration, click Sitelinks.
> - In the For this search result box, complete the URL for which you don't want a specific sitelink URL to appear.
> - In the Demote this sitelink URL box, complete the URL of the sitelink you want to demote.